# Selecting a certain area of a layer in Photoshop script JS

Tags: arrays, photoshop

I'm a newbie. I know i have to use some sort of code like this  docRef.selection.select(*,*,*,*) but I have no idea how to correctly fill those spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;

//(topleft, bottomleft, bottomright, topright)
var shapeRef = [ [10,10], [10,90], [90,90], [90,10] ];
docRef.selection.select(shapeRef);
```

On 100 x 100 pixel  canvas this will select everything with a 10 pixel border

You can also use docRef.selection in other ways:

```
// inverse selection
docRef.selection.invert();

//select all
docRef.selection.selectAll();

//deselect all
docRef.selection.deselect();
```